# Folder Rename using Directory.Move(): Access to Path is Denied

Tags: c#, exception, directory, access-denied

I have Common Network Shared Folder When Folder Rename using Directory. Move(): Access to Path is Denied, Actual Problem is When Folder is open by another System or another process, If Any possible to rename the folder or Close the Folder Open by another system or another process

My Code

```
static void moveToShare()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("\\Share")) Directory.CreateDirectory("\\Share");
    string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmms");
    try
    {
        Directory.Move("\\Output", "\\Share\\" + timestamp);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cant Move Folder: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you wait other system close it ? maybe check directiry is opened on every seconed.

Comment: because if other system open it , and you rename it at same time . maybe have mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You must gain access.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity idnt = new WindowsIdentity(username, password);
WindowsImpersonationContext context = idnt.Impersonate();


if (!Directory.Exists("\\Share"))
   Directory.CreateDirectory("\\Share");
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmms");
try
{
        Directory.Move("\\Output", "\\Share\\" + timestamp);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cant Move Folder: " + e.Message);
}

context.Undo();
```